# Jsoup Could not parse query

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm converting the xpath to Jsoup 
below is my xpath (which is used in my selenium webdriver)

```
String number = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-dojo-attach-point='subNumber']")).getText();
```

equivalent jsoup

```
String number =  doc.select(" >span >data-dojo-attach-point=subNumber").text();
        System.out.println(number);
```

While executing getting below error

```
Could not parse query 'data-dojo-attach-point=subNumber': unexpected token at '=subNumber'
```

HTML:

```
<div class="subHeaders">
            <div class="subHeaderItem">
                <h5 class="smallGray">Number</h5>
                <span data-dojo-attach-point="subNumber">94607506</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

can anyone help this.

Comment: Which version of jsoup?

Comment: Jsoup version 1.11.3

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you could retrieve that data with [selectFirst​(String cssQuery)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#selectFirst-java.lang.String-) and then [html()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html--):

### TestClass:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class TestA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        //this is where chromedriver.exe should be 
        String driverPath = "yourDriverPath";

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath); 

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); ; 

        driver.get("YourURL"); 

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

        String cssSelector = "span[data-dojo-attach-point=subNumber]";

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)));

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("YourURL").get();

        Element subNumber = doc.selectFirst(cssSelector);

        System.out.println(subNumber.html());
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
94607506
```

Note: I've tried the above in my laptop and it's working.

Comment: Thanks , but received empty text

Comment: now received null pointer exception in the above line. (sorry i'm new in Jsoup)

Comment: Let me know how can i check if the webpage completed loaded or not (in dom)

Comment: @Prabu Added full code example. JSoup is an HTML parser, not some kind of embedded browser engine. This means that it's completely unaware of any content that is added to the DOM by Javascript after the initial page load.

Comment: @Rcoddoval Thanks for your help, the above html code not available while connecting my webpage thru Jsoup, but its available in normal case (directly executed from my browsers)

Comment: @Prabu check my edit, it should wait not until that css selector appears. Lemme know if it's working now

Comment: Can we get HTML element by raw xpath example: /html/head

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS Selector.

```
  div.subHeaders > div.subHeaderItem > span

  String number =  doc.select("div.subHeaders > div.subHeaderItem > span").text();
```

If the page has loaded then you will get the text. Use "Try Jsoup" to verify if you are able to get the text.

Click on this [link](http://try.jsoup.org/~JXKEbe42WG-ElJU27EAbU1Eew9w). Click "Fetch URL" and input the URL of the page you are trying to parse and click "Fetch". Let me know if you are able to get the value.

If you don't mind posting the URL here, post the URL here. We will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, tried in Jsoup online site, i 'm not getting the above html portion, i think JSoup not handled for js/jquery

Comment: @Prabhu JSoup is a HTML parser. You need to use selenium to wait for the page to load and the value to be visible in order to get that text.

Comment: @Prabhu If you are already using selenium, then add this condition before extracting the value.                                                                       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.subHeaders > div.subHeaderItem > span")));